# Running an Android 2.x application in a 1.x emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to force an Android project created in Eclipse for the 2.0 platform to run on the 1.5 AVD (emulator).  This is due to the fact that I'm writing an app that will support both the Contacts API and the ContactsContract API.

Does anyone know the magic word to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are really talking about an Android project (folders with .java source files and all the XML files required and so on) then just right click the project folder and hit `Properties`. In the properties window select the `Android` section in the left pane. Now just select the project build target you want to use and hit `Apply`.

EDIT: If you want to provide backwards compatibility for certain features then simply check for the SDK version and decide what to do upon a certain version SDK version.

```
int sdk = new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

if(sdk >= 5) {
    // do whatever you need
}
else {
    // do whatever else you need
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it removes support for the ContactsContract API, which is necessary for the project.

Comment: Oh so you just want to have a backwards compatible application or what?

Comment: Pretty much.  I want to support both API's for retrieving Contacts.  Presently I'm maintaining two versions of the app, and it's costing me in terms of sales, because it creates technical issues for users who don't read the instructions properly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to this question:  [How to use contacts API for Android 1.x and 2.x simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312321/how-to-use-contacts-api-for-android-1-x-and-2-x-simultaneously)

Conditional Classloading is what you're looking for, I think.  In that case, I think you would configure your project as a 1.x project, and it should build and run on 1.x, and then if it detected a 2.x phone, it would use the newer API.